# Order of names in a meshabarach after an aliyah

Tags: tefilla, torah-service, family-members, gabbai, honors

Is there any specific order in the list of names in a meshabarach after an aliyah? For instance, does my wife get listed first,or my parents? Do Grandkids get listed after their parents or only after all my children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no official order, you can do it in any order that you prefer.

Comment: What about the mitzvah of kibbud ov v'aim? Although it is not one of the "official" forms of kovod, I think most parents would rather be mentioned ahead of their grandchildren.

Comment: Also perhaps if you are related to a kohein he should come first.

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful not to mess up the grammatical references. Sometimes the gabbai will say

העולה ואת אשתו פב"פ ואת אביו פב"פ ואת אמו פב"פ ואת בנו פב"פ ואת בנו פב"פ

At a certain point it becomes very unclear who the 'his' is referring to. Is it the father's son? The son's son's son?

The gabbai should either switch to saying ואת בן העולה פב"פ or group the family members into plural groups to avoid an ambiguous 'his' ( eg ואת אשתו פב"פ ואת הוריו פב"פ ופב"פ ואת בניו פב"פ ופב"פ )

Comment: Why (or, by what authority)? Why can't the _gabay_ use "and his son so-and-so" even if the "his" is ambiguous, so long the _gabay_ intends the correct person? We do that, e.g., in the _mi sheberach_ prayer said after the _Tora_ reading on _Shabas_: "them, and their wives, and their sons, and their daughters, and all they have": all _whose_ daughters: the sons'? or the wives'? or the original referents'? If this ambiguity is okay there, why wouldn't it be okay in a _mi sheberach_ said after an _aliya_?

Comment: @msh210 In that case there are no names listed. With names it sounds much more confusing.

Comment: This bothers me, but what bothers me much more is: "the oleh, Yaakov ben Yitchak and his son Reuven ben Yaakov, and his son Shimon ben Yaakov..."  If I just said "his son", I don't need to then say Ploni ben Ploni.